# CSS - Menu not fixed in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, menu, position, fixed

I am working on a website: http://joewebdesign.ro/test/cheope/

The menu is not fixed in **Firefox** and **IE** even though I set "position: fixed"

The div has the following elements:

```
element.style {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;  
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think ie and firefox require a left and top position for it to be fixed.  If you just want it to be fixed to the top of the div then you can use `position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0;` and this will also solve your width problem in chrome

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but that does not make the menu fixed. Any other suggestions? Thank you!